# CollectionAssert of an nested List

Tags: c#, unit-testing, equality

How to assert a nested list too, without 'unnesting' it?

```
        expected.Add(new Customer{
                Edition = "Cust",
                Rarity = "R",
                ID = 1001,
                Name = "John Doe",
                Types = new List<Type_>{
                    new Type_{
                        ID = 1,
                        Name = "abc"
                    }
                },
```

Here the assert:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

That certainly exclude the nested list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that worked for me:

- Generate object hash (such as MD5) that includes the content of the list, this is quite a rigid approach and is seldom useful
- Just write a second assert in the test specifically for that inner list. This is more conventional approach (my favourite)
- Write a new test to only assert inner list. This is more TDD-purist approach

Edit, here is an example of conventional approach:

```
var expected = new List<Type_>{
                    new Type_{
                        ID = 1,
                        Name = "abc"
                    };
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual.Types);
```

Comment: I'm want to try the conventional approach. How to do that best? Do I have to create an expected_type_ list copy first to assert it? I don't know how to address the inner list in an assert only?

Comment: I had this also in mind, but my tested method returns only one custom class (for example Customer). In this class are three others inner lists(Type_, etc.). I could create temporary lists for these inner lists in my tested method, but I can only return one class.